# Really simple delay loading of SVG animation...not working

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

This seems like a simple problem compared to other SVG delay problems people are having.

I have replicated this [text highlight effect](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/WNdeKQJ).

I switched off the CSS hover for the effect so it is always showing.

My version is the pale pink Brilliant Business inside the top text block here: https://leslieh7.sg-host.com/join-us-alt/

I added `transition-delay: 3000ms;` to the SVG and this works on hover but not when the page loads - it is already loaded.

Is `transition-delay` the correct rule to use on the SVG?

Answer (score 1):

Did you really mean `transition-delay`?  From your example, `transition` seems more likely.

As you already realised, the `transition-xxx` properties only apply to when you change the style of an element.  If it's already that style when it is first rendered, there is no change.

If you want the highlight transition/animation to play after the page has loaded, then you probably want to use an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) rather than a transition.

Something like this:

```
<div class="selected">Join us</div>

.selected {
  animation: 3s ease-in forward pinkify;
}

@keyframes pinkify {
  to { fill: pink; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a handler to the [Window load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).  And in that handler add a class to that first element that has the same animation as the hover.

Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("join-us").className.add("selected");
});

.selected {
  transition: 1s;
  fill: pink;
}
```